# How can I join 2 tables having a sub-query?

Tags: sql-server

```
select max(quantity) as Quantity, [Stock ID]
from (select sum(quantity) as quantity, StockID as "Stock ID"
      from Orders
      group by StockID) as quantity
group by [Stock ID]
```

I want to get the max of the sum of stock. Having a sub-query in the from clause was the only thing that worked for me. Now I want to display the ID of the stock but I can't. This code gets the right solution, but for all the rows. I only want one row with the quantity and the ID. s theIre another way I could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The outer max and group by aren't needed because you only have one row for the inner query for the StockId because there is already a group max.  So, if you do MAX, you only get the maximum of 1 row per StockId which is the same as the value itself.

All you need is this, assuming @StockId is a parameter

```
select sum(quantity) as quantity, StockID as "Stock ID"
  from Orders where StockId=@StockId
  group by StockID
```